# Unable to send Pyspark data frame to Kafka topic

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming-kafka

I am trying to send data from a daily batch to a Kafka topic using pyspark, but I currently receive the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 5, in
>    File
> "/usr/local/rms/lib/hdp26_c5000/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py",
> line 548, in save
> self._jwrite.save()   File "/usr/local/rms/lib/hdp26_c5000/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
> line 1133, in **call**   File
> "/usr/local/rms/lib/hdp26_c5000/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py",
> line 71, in deco
> raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace) pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"Invalid call to toAttribute on
> unresolved object, tree: unresolvedalias('shop_id, None)"

The code I am using is as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions

spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
.config("spark.debug.maxToStringFields", 100000) \
.getOrCreate()

df = spark.sql('''select distinct shop_id, item_id 
from sale.data
''')

df.selectExpr("shop_id", "item_id") \
.write \
.format("kafka") \
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "myserver.local:443") \
.option("topic","test_topic_01") \
.save()
```

Currently used versions are:

-Spark 2.1.1.2.6.2.0-205

-Kafka Broker 0.11

Answer (score 1):

Kafka expects that a key and a value is written into its topic. Although the key is not mandatory. It does that by looking at the names of the dataframe columns which should be "key" and "value".

In your query, you are only selecting the column "shop_id", so no key or value column is existing. The error message: "unresolvedalias('shop_id, None)" tells you that the column "shop_id" is selected as the key (as it is the first column), but nothing is interpreted as the *mandatory* value.

You can solve your issue by renaming the column to "value", something like:

```
df = spark.sql('''select distinct shop_id, item_id 
from sale.data
''')

df.withColumn("value", col("shop_id").cast(StringType)) \
.write \
.format("kafka") \
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "myserver.local:443") \
.option("topic","test_topic_01") \
.save()
```

Comment: I tried this, but I receive the following error:

pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"Invalid call to dataType on unresolved object, tree: 'value"

Comment: which type does the column shop_id have? You probably need to cast it to a string...

Comment: Hmmm the type is num, but I tried casting it to a string... I still get the same error. When casting, I am using distinct
  string(shop_id)
 ,string(item_id) in the initial sql statement. Is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not fully aware of Python API, so I cannot really judge. [This](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-cast-column-type/) might help to understand type casting in pyspark. I have also enhanced my answer.

Comment: This is a good starting point - thank you.
My original question was a simplification and I need two columns, so I've edited the original. withColumn() only returns a single column, so I need to investigate how to return multiple columns.

Comment: Glad it helped! In case you want to store multiple columns, you need to think about how you want to store them all together. You could for example make a json representation out of it (by using the SQL built-in function `to_json`. Or you could have one column as the key, the other one as the value.